# Angular + $http issue

Tags: angularjs, http, service

I have json file which consists of 9 products. I created the service which consists of getProducts function (code shown below) which make $http request. When I tried to console log or call the function from controller it prints return object multiple times instead of one time.

```
this.getProducts = function(callback){
    $http.get('/json/products.json',{ cache: true }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        callback(response.data);
    }, 
    function(error){ console.log('error')});
}
```

[image]

Can somebody help me how to get the object from $http request only once.

Thanks

Comment: please post your code about how you called `service.getProducts`(the controller?).

Comment: `$http` returns a promise so instead of using a callback, you can return the promise from `$http`.  Use `return $http.get('/j...`  Look into promises if you don't understand this.

Comment: @sh0ber, I understand the promise. I already tried your method of returning $http.get and this approach also returns the same.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Pengy you can check my code here https://github.com/romeepraj/jwellerystore/blob/master/app/service/service.js https://github.com/romeepraj/jwellerystore/blob/master/app/products/products.js  Thanks a lot for your help